# How does Typo3 handle images that I upload?

Tags: image, logic, typo3

Im curious about the "philsophy" of how Typo3 handles images. So I could directly upload an image for a content element via "select" (direct upload) or I can open a dialog in Typo3 where I can choose in the Fileadmin user_uploads from already uploaded images.

Anyways I heard that Typo3 will always create a duplicate of the selected image and I believe that Typo3 places those duplicates in a temporary directory (which will grow bigger and bigger over the time).

But im not sure how Typo3 will handle those images.. What If I select an image from the user_uploads and then I will rearrange my folder structure in the fileadmin/user_uploads area? Will the image which I refer to my content element still be linked to the user_uploads source even if I move folders around? And what will happen If I erease stuff from the blown up temp/cache folders?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Images uploaded directly in the conntent element are (typically) saved in the **uploads/** folder. Images selected from already uploaded images in **fileadmin/user_uploads/** are copied into the **uploads/** folder. Those images are therefore not "temporary" (unlike files generated on the fly and saved in **typo3temp/** folder) and any deletion of images in the **uploads/** folder will result in missing files which can be easily reverted only by restoring those images from a backup (and possibly also reverting database changes as some inconsistency might have been created if editors kept on working with TYPO3 between the file deletion and restoration).

The idea behind creating copies is that it prevents (accidental) deletion of an image by the user (thus rendering the outputted content incomplete) as the users do not/should not have access to the **uploads/** folder. Any deletion of the original file in **fileadmin/user_uploads/** therefore does not affect page output.